# How to define different keyboard shortcuts for Find In All Files in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to define a different keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio 2017 for the following operation:

- Find in all files (Entire Solution)
- Find in all files (Current Project)

I search inside the available commands and the only I was able to find was the command Edit.FindinFiles (assigned to Ctrl+Shift+F in my environment).

Do you know that is possible to do what I am looking for with some trick?

Answer (score 1):

In VS17 you have two different find Windows. The "normal" with CTRL+F witch is normaly in the top right corner. And theres another find windows with CTRL+SHIFT+F. It has a little bit more functionality and pop out as a independant window, those aren't synchronized. On one the "entire solution" search and on the other "current projekt" search.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I already know and using the different keyboard shortcuts CTRL+F and CTRL+SHIFT+F. I just don't like to select manually the dropdown of CTRL+SHIFT+F to select Entire Solution or Current Project. Have the possibility to define a custom keyboard shortcut for that would be better for me.